# Changing NLA Strip/Action Names

Tags: nla-editor

It seems incredible that I should have to ask this, but it is always such with Blender... How can I change the action strip data names (I'm not even sure what to call them, curse the NLA stack)? Action.002, Action.003, how can I change these labels? This problem is slowing down my work flow enormously.

[image: change this labels?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *N panel > Strip*, at the top of the panel, type the name you want:

[image]

Comment: I'm not worthy. Thank you so much!!